# If $(ax+2)(bx+7)=15x^2+cx+14$ for all values of $x$, and $a+b=8$, what are two possible values for $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First of all, I'm learning English and also doing maths in English, but I'm stuck at this question.  I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

If $(ax+2)(bx+7)=15x^2+cx+14$ for all values of $x$, and $a+b=8$, what are two possible values for $c$?

Comment: Or have you tried comparing terms of equal powers in $x$? This should give $ab=15$ in the quadratic terms, and another equation for the linear terms.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ arbitrary real numbers?

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). We want to see what you have tried or what your ideas are to approach the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We put it as

$$(ax + 2) (bx +7) = 15x^2 + cx +14$$

$$abx^2 +(7a+2b)x + 14 = 15x^2 + cx +14$$

By comparison we take $ab=15$ and $a+b=8$ and solving them we get two cases:

1- $a=3$ and $b=5$, and $c= 7a+2b = 31$.

2- $a=5$ and $b=3$, and $c= 7a+2b = 40$

Comment: Why are you assuming that $a,b,c$ are integers?

Comment: @DietrichBurde is there any other solution to the system of the two equations?

Comment: Actually, no, you are right. But it looks like you concluded the cases from $ab=15$ that $15=3\cdot 5$ or $15=5\cdot 3$. Perhaps you should say that the quadratic equation has only two solutions, which are integral.

Comment: @DietrichBurde No, I considered the system.

Comment: Yes, I know. But perhaps "solving them" is not precise enough for this, although it is clear more or less. The OP should *always* say over which numbers (ring, field etc) the equation should be considered, even if it follows like here.

Comment: That works out nicely for integers this time but what if the question were $(ax+2)(bx+7)=15x^2 + cx + 14$ but were instead told that $a+b=9$ instead?  How exactly did you solve $ab=15, a+b=8\implies a=3;b=5$ or $a=5;b=3$?  How would you solve $ab=15; a+b =9$?

Comment: @fleablood In this case we will have $$a = \frac{9 \pm \sqrt{21}}{2}, \quad  b = 9-a.$$

Comment: My point being (and I believe the point Dietrich Burde was making as well) is that "and solving them" requires more explanation.  In this case it looks like you just assumed $a$ and $b$ must be positive integers that factor $15$ and trial and error yield $\{a,b\} = 3,5$.... BTW you should state $b =\pm \frac{\sqrt{21}}2$ and $c=7a +2b = \frac {63 \pm 9\sqrt{21}}2$.